# Compiling a single .java file in a Maven project

Tags: java, maven

Right now, am using `mvn package exec:java -DskipTests`, which will compile my project just fine, and start a server.

Instead of restarting the server, if a .java file changes, would like to only re-compiling that lone .java file.

Does anyone have a reliable javac command that can compile a single .java file in a Maven project, and put it in target/classes?

Here is the project structure:

```
src/
  main/
    java/
      foo/
        My.java
```

and then it needs to be compiled to this location:

```
target/
   classes/
      foo/
        My.class
```

the following bash script will compile the file if it has no imports.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mkdir -p "$PWD/target/classes/foo";
javac "$PWD/src/main/java/foo/My.java" -d "$PWD/target/classes" -cp "$PWD/src/main/java"
```

but if I include imports in the file, then I need to use a classpath which includes the maven dependencies.

So when I set the classpath using -cp, I need to do something like:

```
-cp "$PWD/src/main/java:$M2_HOME"
```

does anyone know what I should add to the classpath to cover the maven deps necessary for a maven project?

**Update**

The only way I think this would work, is if Maven could bundle all the dependencies used in the first *real* build into one jar file, in a deterministic location. Then if I wanted to compile a single java file, I would reference that jar in the classpath.

Otherwise, it appears that maven append 100s of paths to the CLASSPATH, and has to do some careful calculation to figure out which version of which jar to include the CLASSPATH. It would likely be impossible to be sure which jars were included in the original build. So the only way to know would be for Maven to spit out a new jar of all the library deps in one jar file.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you asking for the command `mvn compile`?

Comment: @SiKing no, I will add an answer soon, you will see what I am after